# Usar Identity com banco existente

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Estou fazendo migração de um sistema para asp core, porém o sistema atualmente tem sua lógica de login feita na procedure, minha dúvida é a seguinte, é possivel usar apenas a autorização do Identity (Roles)?(procurei em vários artigos não achei fazendo com banco existente).

Comment: Você quer fazer o login na "mão" e no sistema controlar o usuário com as *roles*?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode "forçar" a autenticação pesquisando o usuário logado com a regra que você quiser, eu particularmente desenvolvi um app para mobile e coloquei/criei um usuário padrão para fazer o login toda vez que o app tentar acessar a minha página e depois "forço" a autenticação e depois da autenticação eu redirecioano para página desejada.
No meu caso é usuário padrão já cadastrado, mas vc pode fazer a pesquisa pela Role ou passar a Role e se estiver tudo certo você faz o comando abaixo. o parâmetro name é o usuário do meu app que eu passo, eu não verifico a senha por que se trata de app de distribuição interna. A classe SignInManager que é responsável pela autenticação do usuário. Espero ter ajudado

A autenticação está no comando: await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, true);

Meu controller para fazer a autenticação do meu app.

```
public class AppLoginController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;


    public AppLoginController(ApplicationDbContext context, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager)
    {
        _context = context;
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;

    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string name)
    {

        var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(name);

        if (user != null)
        {

           await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, true);

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "MeuController");

        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");


    }
}
}
```